# How to create a user profile image

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, user-interface, firebase-realtime-database

When my user sign up all his user info goes directly into firebase storage and database (such as: username and profile image). When my user sign up the username appears on his profile but no profile image appears how do I fix this code to change that? **I Need The Profile image That My User Signed Up With To Pop Up On His Profile Screen**

```
 import Firebase

class InteractivViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var UsernameText: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var ProfileImage: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var DisplayText: UILabel!

    var DatabaseRef: DatabaseReference!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

       DatabaseRef = Database.database().reference()

  if let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {
        DatabaseRef.child("users").child(userID).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
          // Get user value
          let dictionary = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
         let username = dictionary?["username"] as? String ?? "username"
          if let profileImageUrl = dictionary?["photo"] as? String {

              func getProfileImage(uid: String, success: @escaping (UIImage?)->Void)
          {

              let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("usersImages")
              storageRef.child("\(uid).jpg").getData(maxSize: 1024*1024) { (data, error) in
                  guard let data = data else {return}
                  DispatchQueue.main.async {
                      success(UIImage(data: data))

                  getProfileImage(uid: userID) { image in
                      self.ProfileImage.image = image
                   }
              }
          }
              }
            func upload(image: UIImage, to firebasePath: String, completion: @escaping (String?, Error?) -> Void) {
                //... creates data from the image...
                var data = NSData()
                //Compress the image by any percent
                data = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.8)! as NSData
                //...sets the upload path
                let filePath = "\(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)0)" // path where you wanted to store img in storage
                print(filePath)
                let metaData = StorageMetadata()
                metaData.contentType = "image/jpg"

                let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child(filePath)
                storageRef.putData(data as Data, metadata: metaData){(metaData,error) in
                    if let error = error {
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                        completion(nil, error)
                        return
                    } else {
                        storageRef.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in
                            //Returns the url string to the newly uploaded image so that we can set the user's photoURL database property to this string
                            Database.database().reference().child(firebasePath).setValue(url!.absoluteString)
                            completion(url!.absoluteString, nil)
                        })
                    }
                }

            let image = UIImage(named: "someImage")
            upload(image: image!, to: "Users/\(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)/photoUrls/0", completion: { urlString, error in
                Database.database().reference().child("Users/\(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)/photoUrls/0").setValue(urlString)
            },
                Database.database().reference().child("Users/\(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)/photoUrls/0").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
                    let urlString = snapshot.value as! String
                    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: urlString)!) {(data, response, error) in

                        if let image: UIImage = UIImage(data: data!) {
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                //update the image
                                self.ProfileImage.image = image
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    task.resume()
                }
                   )}

            }


                                   self.UsernameText.text = username
                                       self.DisplayText.text = username


                                       return

                     }
```

Answer (score 0):

you must use the url you retrieved from firebase and download it with their Storage API

```swift
let storage = Storage.storage()
let storageRef = storage.reference()
let ref = storage.reference(forURL: profileImageUrl)
ref.getData(maxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024) { data, error in
   if let error = error {
     // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
  } else {

     self.ProfileImage = UIImage(data: data!)
    self.view.addSubview(self.ProfileImage)
    self.reloadInputViews()
  }
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to store the url that points to the reference in your Storage bucket within the user object in your database. This is the function I use that takes a `UIImage` and `String` denoting the Firebase path and returns the URL of the uploaded image:

```swift
func upload(image: UIImage, to firebasePath: String, completion: @escaping (String?, Error?) -> Void) {
    //... creates data from the image...
    var data = NSData()
    //Compress the image by any percent
    data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.8)! as NSData
    //...sets the upload path
    let filePath = "\(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)0)" // path where you wanted to store img in storage
    print(filePath)
    let metaData = StorageMetadata()
    metaData.contentType = "image/jpg"

    let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child(filePath)
    storageRef.putData(data as Data, metadata: metaData){(metaData,error) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            completion(nil, error)
            return
        } else {
            storageRef.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in
                //Returns the url string to the newly uploaded image so that we can set the user's photoURL database property to this string
                Database.database().reference().child(firebasePath).setValue(url!.absoluteString)
                completion(url!.absoluteString, nil)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

To upload the image and update the user object in the database, you could do this:

```swift
let image = UIImage(named: "someImage")
upload(image: image, to: "Users/\(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)/photoUrls/0", completion: { urlString, error in
    Database.database().reference().child("Users/\(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)/photoUrls/0").setValue(urlString)
}
```

Then, you could grab the image via:

```swift
Database.database().reference().child("Users/\(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)/photoUrls/0").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
    let urlString = snapshot.value as! String
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: urlString)!) {(data, response, error) in

        if let image: UIImage = UIImage(data: data!) {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                //update the image
                self.ProfileImage.image = image
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: Database.database().reference().child("Users/\(Auth.auth().currentUser.uid)/photoUrls/0").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        let urlString = snapshot.value as! String
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: urlString)!) {(data, response, error) in

            if let image: UIImage = UIImage(data: data!) {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    //update the image
                    self.ProfileImage.image = image
                }
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }  ERROR

Comment: Extra argument in call

Comment: I am not home but this is the code ai use for an app that has been deployed and we have no issues with it. It likely isn’t being applied correctly. Once I get some time I’ll see if I can revise it for you

Comment: I really appreciate that

Comment: Here's a link explaining how you're implementing it wrong. It's a simple Swift formatting thing. https://pastebin.com/zj2ugaLy

Comment: I did exactly that and nothing still change

Comment: Well what issue are you getting because there isn’t an extra argument in the code I sent you

Comment: extra argument error did go away but the profile image still haven't appeared

Comment: You’ll have to employ regular debugging techniques to make sure you’re implementing it right. Set breakpoints in callbacks and make sure all methods are being called and returning the expected data. There’s only so much I can do for you though I do know this technique works.